# how can i solve Reverse for 'Add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['agregar/(?P<producto_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z'] error?

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a tutorial from django, and i getting this error when trying to add an href button, i use django 4.0.4 version and python 3.9 version.

Models.py

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    serie_producto = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('agregar/<int:producto_id>/', agregar_producto, name="Add"),
    ...
```

]

template catalogo that causes te error. The message error highlights `{% url 'Add' producto.id %}`

```
{% for producto in response %}
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card" style="height: 10rem; width: 23rem; margin: 5px 0px;">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-tittle">{{producto.nombre}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{producto.marca}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{producto.precio}}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'Add' producto.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar al carrito</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

view.py

```
from tienda.models import Producto
from tienda.carrito import Carrito
def catalogo(request):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Producto/"
    response = requests.get(url, auth=('admin','duoc'))
    datos = response.json()
    return render(request, 'catalogo.html', {'response' : datos })

def agregar_producto(request, producto_id):
    carrito = Carrito(request)
    producto = Producto.objects.get(id=producto_id)
    carrito.agregar(producto)
    return redirect("Tienda")
```

**The Problem**
When i got to the catalogo template i get the before mentioned error, the api works perfectly when i dont use the {% url 'Add' producto.id %}, i think that is something with the id, cant read it maybe??, i dont know if is this. I have no idea how to solve this or what is wrong.

how can i solve this ?

any suggestion or help are welcome.

EDIT:

Complete error message from cmd:

```
File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\giova\Desktop\Pagina-Web-Django-con-Api\tienda\views.py", line 17, in catalogo
    return render(request, 'catalogo.html', {'response' : datos })
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 958, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 472, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 802, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'Add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['agregar/(?P<producto_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that reads `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and formatting as code. Instead of trying to fit part of the error message into the title, please  use a title that summarizes and clearly asks the question. Finally, please make sure to **ask a question** - "any suggestion or help are welcome" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: ready, i just added the complete error message and changed the title for a question, i hope that the question is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys i just fin the error to my problem, i going to post here for other people with the same problem.

In my serializer i dont specified the 'id'

```
class ProductoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer) :
class Meta:
    model = Producto
    fields = ['url', 'nombre', 'codigo', 'precio', 'serie_producto', 'marca']
```

soo, the solution is:

```
class ProductoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer) :
class Meta:
    model = Producto
    fields = ['id' #here ,'url', 'nombre', 'codigo', 'precio', 'serie_producto', 'marca']
```

Comment: Alternatively you can do `fields = '__all__'` to render all fields in the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'Add' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['agregar/(?P<producto_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

This error tells you that the view with name `'Add'` expects an integer argument, but you passed it an empty string `''`. To debug this, you can add `print(datos)` before your `render()` call. Most likely you will see a list of JSON objects with at least one that has `id: ""`.